# Oracle from .Net with a 64 bit client

Tags: .net, oracle, 64-bit

Has anyone had any luck of using Oracle from .Net on a 64 bit machine, and using the UDT capabilities of Oracle?

I've been able to use an x64 ODP.Net client, but cannot find one with any support for UDTs.

Thanks

Nick

[Edit]
I've posted an answer below. The latest (as of December 2008) release is 11.1.0.7. This has support for 64 bit and UDT.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use 11.1.0.7 release. This has UDT support and works with 32 and 64 bit.

Answer (score 1):

UDT capability is only listed in 11g clients and the latest 64 bit client is 10.2.0.3.

Not the answer you wanted, but the one that Oracle seems to be giving.

Actually I'm glad you asked this question.  We're working on migrating to 64 bit server code and I wouldn't have thought to check for this.

Answer (score 0):

I've been trying for some time to get the 64-bit edition of Windows Server 2003 to connect to an Oracle 8i instance. It doesn't seem to be possible other than doing it through a 32-bit VM.

Forced upgrading can really suck!